# Choosing proper centripedal force in Newtonian gravitational forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, simulations, centrifugal-force

I am trying to do an orbit simulation, I took Newton's law of Newtonian gravitational forces. It seems to work correct, but I can't really determine the velocity of an object needed to stay in free fall. I didn't want to use the masses in our planet systems, as the values are to high (in kg)

So when my earth's mass is 1, what should be the masses be of the orbiting satellites and what should the initial velocity be to stay in freefall, when I want to altitude be 50 units (meters).

It would be nice, if you could give me some hints!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed

Comment: i've already read about orbital speed, i've measured the acceleration and than transformed the formula to get the needed velocity out of it, **v = sqrt(ac *r)** as i couldn't get any proper results (satellites are never coming back) i've asked the question here..

Comment: Maybe you can help me out, to simplyfy my problem i am using "earth mass" where earth is 1 and moon 0.0123. What about distance, do i have to change the distance unity as well from km to something else?

Comment: You have to change Newton's constant: $G$.

Comment: I think you would make better progress if you used the actual masses.  Your attempt to simplify is probably making things more complicated.

Comment: garyp i absolutely agree, but however i think, that i am not so far away. @jinawee **3.88E-25** can this be correct to be the universal Constant in Earth Mass?

Comment: I get: $G'=7\cdot10^{-11}\cdot (6\cdot10^{24})=3\cdot10^{39} Nm^2/kg$

Comment: What you need is a proper scale-down factor to try and fit large orbits of satellites around the earth onto your screen so everything is visible properly. What you need to scale-down here is not earth's mass, but the radii of the orbits. So let the mass of the earth be the same, and also the definition of other units, and try to simulate the exact distances which would exist. Then scale-down to make the simulation fit your screen (eg. 500 mtrs -> 50 pixels)

Comment: Did i understand it right, that i should just fit the results of the new Positions into my scale? like fit(value, oldmin, oldmax, newmin, newmax) ? How can i determine, what max is?

Comment: @jinawee how on Earth did you do that math? $10^{-11}*10^{24}=10^{39}$?? Punch those numbers into your calculator again

Comment: There was supposed to be a square after the brackets.

Comment: ....and i am completely lost...